# PubSub connectivity issue when deployed in GKE

Tags: java, binding, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-stream

We are using Spring Cloud Stream, Spring boot application to connect to the PubSub from microservice. The application works locally connecting to a specific project and pubsub in cloud. However when I deploy the application in the GKE , I am getting a permission denied error.

Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while building outbound endpoint at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:210) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:97) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:151) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindProducer(BindingService.java:268) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:243) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:287) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58) at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:48) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34) at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:893) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) at com.sensormatic.tvc.InventoryServiceApplication.main(InventoryServiceApplication.java:14) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action. at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:55) at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72) at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60) at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97) at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68) at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1123) at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:435) at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:900) at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:811) at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:675) at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:507) at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:482) at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:678) at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:397) at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:459) at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63) at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:546) at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:467) at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:584) at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57) at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112) at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient.getTopic(TopicAdminClient.java:517) at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient.getTopic(TopicAdminClient.java:472) at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.PubSubAdmin.getTopic(PubSubAdmin.java:117) at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.makeSureTopicExists(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:118) at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:63) at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:45) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:193) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:97) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:151) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindProducer(BindingService.java:268) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:243) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:287) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58) at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:48) at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34) at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:893) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) at com.sensormatic.tvc.InventoryServiceApplication.main(InventoryServiceApplication.java:14) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action. at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526) ... 23 common frames omitted

Comment: Please, format a log output as multi-line code. It is very hard to read it from here in the current state.

Comment: @ArtemBilan sorry initially I was having issues with format. Now I am able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved, I was missing the projectId for the pubsub

spring_cloud_gcp_pubsub_projectId:XXXX

And the application was talking some other pubsub present in other project